# A field or property with the name was not found on the selected data source

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have an Entity Data Model with two entities in it "Roles" and "Users". There is a navigation property from I have a EntityDataSource and a GridView. The EntityDataSource points to the Users entity and has an Include="Roles" parameter.

I've added a BoundField in the GridView that points to RoleName, a property of the entity Roles. However, when I execute the code I get the above error.

I have used very similar code successfully in another application. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Here is my EntityDataSource:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=pbu_checklistEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="pbu_checklistEntities" EnableDelete="True" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Users" Include="Role">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

And here is the BoundField:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="RoleName" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="RoleName" />
```

Comment: I guess the "RoleName" is not right spelled as the property name in your datasource ..

Comment: No, it is definitely named that in both the underlying datasource (MSSQL) and in the entity data model.

Comment: In Roles the columns are ID, RoleName, RoleDescription, EditPermissions, EditBS, EditLibrary, EditSecurity, EditFinAid, EditStudentLife, EditStudentMin, EditRegistrar.
In Users ID, UserID, RoleID

Comment: Despite of my answer I am confused now: Is it `Role` (single reference) or `Roles` (collection) in the `User` entity? And what is `RoleName` then? Shouldn't it be `Role.Name` or `Role.RoleName`? Or do you have a `Select` statement in the EntityDataSource which projects `Role.Name` to `RoleName` as an alias?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot use an `asp:BoundField` for a property of a related navigation property. You can only use an `asp:TemplateField` and then bind it as readonly with `Eval` (**not** `Bind`). BoundFields are always using `Bind` internally, that's the reason why it doesn't work. I had to figure this out myself some time ago:

[Columns of two related database tables in one ASP.NET GridView with EntityDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2284374/270591)

Comment: Thanks! That is a great help.

Comment: The linked question addresses the issue more generally but +1 for this question and answer since it came up in my search--the question is more directly related to the answer.

Comment: This only seems to be true in IIS 6 and not IIS 7. Can anyone confirm or deny this difference?

Comment: Yes John Bledsoe, I only ran in to this issue when trying to deploy a project I had developed on VS 2013/IIS 7 on a VS 2010/IIS 6 setup. I had no issues when testing in my VS 2013/IIS 7 environment. Converting everything to TemplateFields worked for me.