# Entity's Navigation Properties are HashSets and can't be bound to a control

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an entity called Employee that has a Navigation Property called Groups.

Groups maps to the Group entity which has a property for Name.

To set up the relational data, I implemented the answer to this question :
[Columns of two related database tables in one ASP.NET GridView with EntityDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284374/columns-of-two-related-database-tables-in-one-asp-net-gridview-with-entitydataso)

I have an entity for Employees that also includes their Groups:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="GroupsByEmployeeSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=SafetyContext" DefaultContainerName="SafetyContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Employees" Include="Groups" Where="it.[EID] == @EmpID">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" ControlID="GridView1" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I then try to bind the Name of the Group in another Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView3" DataSourceID="GroupsByEmployeeSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="GroupsByEmployee" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Groups.Name") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

This throws an error saying that Groups doesn't have a property Name. After asking a question about it here - [DataBinding: Generic.HashSet`1 does not contain a property with the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575828/databinding-generic-hashset1-does-not-contain-a-property-with-the-name) I realized that this was because Groups is a HashSet. This made more sense after I looked at the generated code for the entity object :

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Employee_Action = new HashSet<Employee_Action>();
        this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public long EID { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SESA { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee_Action> Employee_Action { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

In the constructor, the navigation properties are created as HashSets. Unfortunately, after reading about HashSets I realized that they can only be iterated through. So now I have a Navigation Property that I basically cannot access through the ways I normally bind data to controls.

I am unsure of what I need to do to access Navigation Properties. Do I change the generated code to something other than HashSets? Is there a way to #Eval() Groups and actually get the properties of the Group instead of the properties of the HashSet? Am I supposed to cast Groups in the #Eval call? I'm very lost as to how to get the Entity represented by the Navigation Properties of an entity. If the answer is to do it programmatically, then what event should I work with?

Answer (score 0):

Since Groups is a collection of Group items, what are you actually trying to display in your column? The first group in the collection? or maybe all groups in the collection separated by commas?

You could try;

`Groups.First().Name`

or

`string.Join(",", Groups.Select(g => g.Name).ToArray())`