# Need to get data of related column in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="name=InfowareEntities" 
      DefaultContainerName="InfowareEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
      EntitySetName="StudentModules" 
      Select="it.[AdmissionNo], it.[ModuleCode], it.[Status]"
      Where="it.[Status]==@Status AND it.[AdmissionNo]==@AdmissionNo">
           <WhereParameters>
               <asp:Parameter  Name="Status" Size="10" Type="String" />
               <asp:Parameter  Name="AdmissionNo" Size="7" Type="int64" />
            </WhereParameters>
  </asp:EntityDataSource
```

I need to get module description of this module code from `Module` table, here `Module` code is primary key in `Module` table and foreign key in `StudentModules` table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Include="Module" then you can reference "Module.Description" (or whatever). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.include(v=vs.110).aspx and [Columns of two related database tables in one ASP.NET GridView with EntityDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284374/columns-of-two-related-database-tables-in-one-asp-net-gridview-with-entitydataso)

Comment: `<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="name=InfowareEntities" 
                            DefaultContainerName="InfowareEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
                            EntitySetName="StudentModules" Include="Module"
                            Select="it.[AdmissionNo], it.[ModuleCode], it.[Status], Module.ModuleDescription"
                            Where="it.[Status]==@Status AND it.[AdmissionNo]==@AdmissionNo"></asp:EntityDataSource>`  ** This throws an error**

Comment: 'Module.ModuleDescription' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near member access expression, line 1, column 62.

Comment: Have you configured the relationship in Entity Framework? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have a navigation key named Module which relates ModuleCode in StudentModules and Modules table. I am using Include="Module" and in Select I am adding Module.ModuleDescription but it throws and error.

Comment: Your include might need to be Include="StudentModules.Module" depending on what the models look like. If that doesn't work edit your question with the models displayed.